# Javascript newbie: why is the value not printed out?

Tags: javascript

I am just starting learning JavaScript, and have a question that I am not able to understand.

I have an HTML file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="test.js" />
    <!-- <script></script> -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and my test.js is like this:

```
document.writeln("test");
```

Strangely enough, I do not see the string "test" printed out on the web page. It doesn't print until I remove the commented out line of code in the HTML file.

Also, when I try to replace `<script></script>` with `<script/>`, there is no output either.

The question here is why the code `<script></script>` is related to the output?

Test was done on Chrome 10, and IE 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a shot in the dark, but try replacing:

```
<script language="javascript" src="test.js" />
```

with:

```
<script language="javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

I've had browsers in the past get fussy about that and not properly import the JavaScript in the former case.  Technically the tag is self-closing, but it's actually expected to have a closing tag.

**Edit:** Following @David Dorward's comment, I did a bit of searching through specifications.  I don't know which version of HTML you're using for your page, but it's probably being served as `text/html` and interpreted by most browsers as HTML 4.01.  (Correct me if I'm wrong on this one, I'm not terribly well versed in HTML versions.)

There's a lot about the `script` tag [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), and the interesting part is that all of the examples, be they with embedded script or a referenced script file, all supply a closing tag.  A little more digging turned up [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3) note in the XHTML 1 specification.  It basically states that if a tag is *meant* to have content and just happens to be empty, it still needs to be closed with the full closing tag.  This `script` element *is* technically empty.  It's referencing an external script, but it doesn't *contain* that external script.

Now, these are different specifications of course.  But their DTD's [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) are very similar with regards to the `script` element.  Compare them both to, say, the `br` or `hr` elements which specify that they are empty whereas the `script` elements do not.

Comment: Self-closing is an XML concept, it only applies with an XML MIME type (like application/xhtml+xml but not text/html)

Comment: you are not shooting in the dark, script tag has to be closed `<script language="javascript" src="test.js"></script>` way not `<script language="javascript" src="test.js" />` way be it XHTML or HTML document.

Comment: @Kumar: Indeed.  @David Dorward's comment prompted me to do a bit of digging and edit my answer accordingly.  What I found was just from some brief Googling, so I'm sure there's more to it.  But it's definitely a good learning exercise for me :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't properly escape the `<script>` tag. Precisely, you did it, but you commented it out in this line:

```
<!-- <script></script> -->
```

That line should be:

```
</script>
```

Next, if you want to test out if your scripts work, use `alert("your text")` and you'll see a popup window.

The best way to see your results is to use `console.log("your log text")` and you'll see your debug info in Chrome's console. This will also work with Firefox if you have Firebug installed and possibly with Safari, although I haven't used it personally.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` needs to have a separate closing tag

```
<script language="javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you giving HTML 3.2 examples?